# How to give confirmation for deletion through link?

Tags: 6, forms

I have tabular format data and each row I have an edit and delete links , on clicking on the delete link it should ask for a confirmation to delete and if press delete only I need to delete. Now its asking for confirmation but not deleting any. Instead its giving me a blank page. Is it because it's submitted to the same function? It's not going to the `products_delete_confirm_submit()` on submission by the way. Or is there any workaround for this?

Here is the try :

**Menu call back:**

```
 function mailusers_menu() {
     $items['mailusers/usergroup/delete'] = array(
        'title' => 'Delete User group',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('products_delete_confirm', 3),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'access arguments' => array('access admin tab'),
      );
 return $items;
}
```

**callback function**

```
function products_delete_confirm($form,$product_code) {
$form['_product'] = array(
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $product_code,);
//$form['#action'] = url("mailusers/products_delete_confirm_submit");
//      //drupal_set_message($product_code);

return confirm_form($form,t('Are you sure you want to delete '.$product_code.' Product?'),
        isset($_GET['destination']) ? $_GET['destination'] : "mailusers",t('This action cannot be undone.'),t('Delete'),t('Cancel'));

}
```

**Delete submit handler:**

```
function products_delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
  $form_values = $form_state['values'];
  if ($form_state['values']['confirm']) {
  $param = $form_state['values']['_product'];
    drupal_set_message(t('Product ' .$param.' will get deleted.'));                             
    db_query('DELETE FROM {content_type_usergroup} WHERE vid = %d', $param);
    drupal_set_message(t('usergroup has been deleted.'));          
    drupal_goto('mailusers');
 }
}
```

And in the table I am calling the delete link `href="mailusers/usergroup/delete/10"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother testing the value of confirm, the user is only given a choice to submit or go back (with cancel link).

```
function products_delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
  $param = $form_state['values']['_product'];
  drupal_set_message(t('Product ' .$param.' will get deleted.'));                             
  db_query('DELETE FROM {content_type_usergroup} WHERE vid = %d', $param);
  drupal_set_message(t('usergroup has been deleted.'));          
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'mailusers';
}
```

Also, your access callback is set to TRUE, which bypass all permission checking.

**Final answer**

It should be `products_delete_confirm(&$form_state, $product_code)`, see the example at https://www.drupal.org/node/751826#creating, you were messing with your form structure.

Comment: But what will have in $form_state['values']['confirm'] then ?

Comment: You should still have the value 1, indeed. If your submit is still not called, post the whole code, including potential form_alters

Comment: i removed the access callback and then its submitting though i cant give **function products_delete_confirm($form,$product_code)** like this when giving $form it gives me **Cannot use string offset as an array** error

Comment: It should be products_delete_confirm($form_state, $product_code)

Comment: this was the cause of getting the blank page , when i checked the error log !